# Q: python (using cutadapt in bash script on cluster): libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, unix

I'm running a bash script on a cluster in which the program cutadapt (which utilizes python) is used.

Before I run my script, I loaded python version 3.7.0 and cutadapt

```
alias python=python3
module load python/3.7.0
pip3 install --user --upgrade cutadapt
```

and then send it off via `qsub` but the job keeps aborting early & I keep getting the following error:

```
/u/local/apps/python/3.7.0/bin/python3: 
error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` since `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` shows that the `/u/local/apps/python/3.7.0/lib` is preferentially listed.

Also, `ldd /u/local/apps/python/3.7.0/bin/python3` shows that `libpython3.7m.so.1.0` is found and points to:

```
libpython3.7m.so.1.0 => 
/u/local/apps/python/3.7.0/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 (0x00007f66e01f6000)
```

Additionally, calling cutadapt in the same manner as my script appears to be working properly:

```
~/.local/bin/cutadapt

This is cutadapt 2.3 with Python 3.7.0
Command line parameters:

Run "cutadapt --help" to see command-line options.
See https://cutadapt.readthedocs.io/ for full documentation.
```

My peer has run pretty much the exact same code and script and has had no issues with the script aborting/this error message.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions as to how I can troubleshoot this issue!

**Edit (Thank you for your feedback!):**

This is the script I submitted (which is nearly identical to my peer's aside from a different home directory on the cluster and different output directory):

```
#-- trim00s.sh --#
#!/bin/bash
#runs cutadapt on files 01-09

for i in {1..9}
do
fastq="Index0${i}.for.fq"
trimmedFastq="Index0${i}_trimmed.for.fq"
/u/home/e/evanderw/.local/bin/cutadapt -a GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACNNNNNNATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG -a "A{10}" -a "T{10}" -m 15 -q 30 -o ../../04_trimmed/lane_2/$trimmedFastq $fastq
done
```

The `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the following after I first log onto the cluster (I'm guessing it's automatically set to these libraries as a default for this cluster?):

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/mpi/intel64/lib:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/itac/intel64/itac/slib_impi4:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/compiler/lib/intel64:
/opt/intel/mic/coi/host-linux-release/lib:
/opt/intel/mic/myo/lib:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/mpirt/bin/intel64:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/ipp/lib/intel64:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/mkl/lib/intel64:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/tbb/lib/intel64
```

But then it changes after I have done `alias python=python3` and `module load python/3.7.0` to:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/u/local/apps/python/3.7.0/lib:
/u/local/compilers/intel/17.0.1/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/mkl/lib/intel64:
/u/local/apps/xz/5.2.3/lib:
/u/local/apps/openssl/1.1.1/lib:
/u/local/apps/mpfr/3.1.5/gcc-4.9.3/lib:
/u/local/apps/hdf5/1.8.18/gcc-4.4.7-shared/lib:
/u/local/compilers/gcc/4.9.3/lib:
/u/local/compilers/gcc/4.9.3/lib64:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/mpi/intel64/lib:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/itac/intel64/itac/slib_impi4:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/compiler/lib/intel64:
/opt/intel/mic/coi/host-linux-release/lib:
/opt/intel/mic/myo/lib:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/mpirt/bin/intel64:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/ipp/lib/intel64:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/mkl/lib/intel64:
/u/local/compilers/intel-cs/2013.0.028/composer_xe/tbb/lib/intel64
```

Comment: Where are you setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH?  LD_LIBRARY_PATH is normally blank, and I believe qsub sources one of the dot files (.bash_profile?) in your home directory.  Ask your peer which dot file he is setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in and use that one.

Comment: Show us the submitted script, which is where the problem can be found.

Comment: You should print LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the script. Just in case ... Note the shebang (#!/bin/bash) should be the first line.

Comment: Thanks @mcoolive - you helped me fix my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I updated the script to ensure that the shebang was the first line & then printed off the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash

#-- trim00s.sh --#
#runs cutadapt on files 01-09

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH >foo.txt

for i in {1..9}
do
fastq="Index0${i}.for.fq"
trimmedFastq="Index0${i}_trimmed.for.fq"
/u/home/e/evanderw/.local/bin/cutadapt -a GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACNNNNNNATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG -a "A{10}" -a "T{10}" -m 15 -q 30 -o ../../04_trimmed/lane_2/$trimmedFastq $fastq
done
```

The error still persisted & the resulting `foo.txt` file was completely blank, meaning `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was reset to blank while the script was running via `qsub`.

So, I included a line in my script to now add the directory for the library my code was having problems finding to my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` & it worked!

```
#!/bin/bash

#-- trim00s.sh --#
#runs cutadapt on files 01-09

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/u/local/apps/python/3.7.0/lib


for i in {1..9}
do
fastq="Index0${i}.for.fq"
trimmedFastq="Index0${i}_trimmed.for.fq"
/u/home/e/evanderw/.local/bin/cutadapt -a GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACNNNNNNATCTCGTATGCCGTCTTCTGCTTG -a "A{10}" -a "T{10}" -m 15 -q 30 -o ../../04_trimmed/lane_2/$trimmedFastq $fastq
done
```